# do you multiply the 120 V ac with same DC 2500 mAh ?

Tags: lithium-ion

I have 2500 mAh on the battery and 3.7 V normal voltage and I get 55 watts for the pack in DC, then after changing my voltage to 120 AC, how can I calculate the wattage? I mean multiply the 120 V ac with same DC 2500 mAh on the battery? point is does it change? the mAh on the battery ?

Comment: (55 watts * inverter efficiency) = output wattage, (55 watts * inverter efficiency) / 120V = output current (RMS)

Comment: You should thoroughly read the info in the last comment by mkeith as posted in this question : https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/372758/152903

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE :-) You already asked this question as part of the clarification comments on [your other question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/372758/101852). Therefore this is a duplicate. If you asked this because you haven't yet had an answer to your other question, please read [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers) topic in the Help Center. That explains what to do when no-one answers your question. Again, welcome.

Comment: You're mangling together completely unrelated units.  mAh is not a measure of wattage or current.  It's the battery's storage capacity.

Comment: Guys please, all I want to know is this: we have W=V * A ......then calculate this for me in DC first and then after AC ? that's it, whats my voltage and amp and wattage